# wordpress shows an array in the home page

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Wordpress print out an array in the home page before the html page
The array contains lots of key/value pair

```
Array ( [E_ERROR] => 1 [E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR] => 4096 [E_WARNING] => 2 [E_PARSE] => 4 [E_NOTICE] => 8 [E_STRICT] => 2048 [E_DEPRECATED] => 8192 [E_CORE_ERROR] => 16 [E_CORE_WARNING] => 32 [E_COMPILE_ERROR] => 64 [E_COMPILE_WARNING] => 128 [E_USER_ERROR] => 256 [E_USER_WARNING] => 512 [E_USER_NOTICE] => 1024 [E_USER_DEPRECATED] => 16384 [E_ALL] => 32767 [DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT] => 1 [DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS] => 2 [TRUE] => 1 [FALSE] => [ZEND_THREAD_SAFE] => [ZEND_DEBUG_BUILD] => [NULL] => [PHP_VERSION] => 5.6.30 [PHP_MAJOR_VERSION] => 5 [PHP_MINOR_VERSION] => 6 [PHP_RELEASE_VERSION] => 30 [PHP_EXTRA_VERSION] => [PHP_VERSION_ID] => 50630 [PHP_ZTS] => 0 [PHP_DEBUG] => 0 [PHP_OS] => Linux [PHP_SAPI] => cgi-fcgi [DEFAULT_INCLUDE_PATH] => .:/usr/lib/php5.6 [PEAR_INSTALL_DIR] => /usr/lib/php5.6 [PEAR_EXTENSION_DIR] => /usr/lib/php5.6/extensions/ [PHP_EXTENSION_DIR]
```

How can i get rid of this aaray

Answer (score 1):

Look for the function call *get_defined_constants* in **every** file that is being used to create the page.